# how to add a new Object from user input

Tags: php, arrayobject

i would like to add user input as a new Object as i can see to find how to do that

```
<form method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" name="userinput">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
$obj = new obj('userinput');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it like this way:

```
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->{"userinput"} = $_POST['userinput'];
```

Or if you already had an existing stdClass object:

```
$foo = (array)$foo;
$foo['userinput'] = $_POST['userinput'];
$foo = (object)$foo;
```

now print the value as:

```
echo $foo->userinput; // should display your value
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you please like my answer :)